# Passing a class to a function, giving error

Tags: c++, function, class

BankDatabase bank is the class object:

```
class BankDatabase
{
private:
    Customer* customers[25];
    Account *accounts[25];
    int count;
public:
    BankDatabase();
    Account* getAccount(int accountNum);
    Customer* getCustomer(int accountNum);
    void display();
    void createAccount();
};

class Customer //CUSTOMER CLASS
{
private:
    string fullName;
    int accountNumber;
    string address;
    int phoneNumber;
public:
    Customer();
    Customer(string name, int acc, string add, int phone);
    int getAccountNum() const;
    string getName() const;
    string toString() const;
        /*bool Customer::operator> (Customer* a);*/
    };

    class Account //ACCOUNT CLASS
{
protected:
    int accountNumber;
    int PIN;
    double totalBalance;
public:
    Account();
    Account(int acc, int P, double bal);
    bool validatePIN(int pin);
    int getAccountNum() const;
    double getTotalBalance() const;
    virtual string toString() const;
    void credit(double amount);
    virtual bool debit(double amount);
    /*bool Account::operator> (Account* a);*/
};
```

The function prototype is

```
void AccountAccess(class bank); //This might be error
```

which is before main. int main:

```
    int main()
{
    BankDatabase bank;

    int decision;
    bool goodInput;
    bool isDone = false;

    do
    {
        cout << "Welcome to the Bank of Cthulhu!" << endl;
        cout << endl;
        do
        {
            cout << "Please select an option from the main menu: " << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cout << "1) Create an account" << endl;
            cout << "2) Access your account" << endl;
            cout << "3) Exit" << endl;
            cout << endl;
            cin >> decision;
            if (decision == 1)
            {
                //bank.createAccount(); this works
                goodInput = true;
            }
            else if (decision == 2)
            {
                AccountAccess(bank);
                goodInput = true;
            }
            else if (decision == 3)
            {
                isDone = true;
                goodInput = true;
            }
            else
                goodInput = false;
        } while (!goodInput);

    } while (!isDone);

    return 0;
}
```

and the actual function I am putting bank into is

```
void AccountAccess(BankDatabase b)
{ //Function that allows the user to access their account
    int accInput;
    int pin;
    bool goodInput;
    do
    {
        cout << "Enter account number or press 1 to return to the main menu: ";
        cin >> accInput;
        if(b.getAccount(accInput) != 0)
        {
                goodInput = true;
                break;
        }
        else if (accInput == 0)
        {
            cout << "Returning to main menu..." << endl;
            cout << endl;
            goodInput = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (b.getAccount(accInput) == 0)
        {
            cout << "Account not found. Please try again." << endl;
            goodInput = false;
        }
    } while (!goodInput);

    return;
}
```

giving me the error "'void AccountAccess(bank)' cannot convert argument 1 from 'BankDatabase' to 'bank'

I have tried several variations, but I'm not sure how to fix this and I know it's something simple. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Is this C++? What is the definition of `BankDatabase`?  Why are you passing `BankDatabase` by-value?

Comment: Please see [this page](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) for how to post code that is not working.

Comment: Please provide a [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: showing a minimal complete example that demonstrates the problem, might get you better help. But you might try making the parameter a reference `(BankDatabase& bank)` and use the same parameter name in both the declaration and the definition.

Comment: Are there any other warning or error messages before this one? If so, post the first such message.

Comment: That is the only error, will edit post to give more of an example

Comment: You overlooked the "Complete" part of MCVE

Comment: What is `bank` declared as in `main`? What is the **complete** definition of `BankDatabase`???

Comment: Edited and should be complete

Comment: It's nowhere near complete. There's no `main` function, etc.  "complete" means someone can copy-paste exactly what you wrote and compile it and see the same error.

Comment: Why don't you define it as `void AccountAccess(BankDatabase);` since that is the type you want to pass.  You might also want to pass it by reference unless you don't want changes propogated.

Comment: void AccountAccess(BankDatabase); gives even more errors

Comment: @bankey you probably made some other mistake too. *But we can't say exactly what because you refuse to post a complete example*.

Comment: Example should be complete.

Comment: @bankey, I think M.M's answer and mine together should get you further along...

Comment: No it isn't. The first problem is that `Customer* customers[25];` fails to compile because `Customer` is not defined.  There are *dozens* of other such mistakes.  To verify your post please do this: load up a new file, copy and paste in the code from this question into the new file, and then compile the new file. If you do not get exactly the same error you are asking about,  then you're doing it wrong.

Comment: What you're doing is like booking your car into the mechanics to fix it because the engine won't start, and then you unbolt the battery and drop that in by itself.  Or drive in someone else's car.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

First, you don't have a `copy constructor` for `BankDatabase`.

The function `AccountAccess` is declared as passing the `BankDatabase` instance **by value** instead of **by reference**. Because of that, the compiler wants to pass a copy of the instance. To do that you need a copy constructor in your class, as in

```
BankDatabase(const BankDatabase& rhs);
```

Or you can simply declare and define the function `AccountAccess` with a reference parameter:

```
void AccountAccess(BankDatabase& bank);

...

void AccountAccess(BankDatabase& b)
{
....
```

That way no copying need be done and you'll more likely get what you're really after. But, I would also use the same parameter name in both places.

Comment: There's an implicitly-generated copy-constructor.  (Which may cause incorrect behaviour at runtime, but would not generate a compilation error)

Comment: @M.M That may be, but it's doubtful that the default copy-ctor is what is desired (and rarely is).

Answer (score 2):

This is a mistake:

```
void AccountAccess(class bank); //This might be error
```

You have declared a function called `AccountAccess` whose argument should be an object of class `bank`.

It should be:

```
void AccountAccess(BankDatabase bank);
```

which declares a function called `AccountAccess` whose argument should be an object of class `BankDatabase`.

Comment: @Gread.And.Powerful.Oz yeah he seems to be making his code up as he goes along. Originally that line was different and he edited it.

Comment: @M.M I don't know your vendetta on me. The first time I posted on here I posted my enter code and I was told not to do that so I stopped doing so, and now you are basically telling me to post all my code. I have posted enough for others to run, and I constantly get told different ways of trying to post code, so excuse me if I'm a newbie and am only posting the way people told me to post in the past. Anyway I fixed the problem. I was defining the function prototype before I declared BankDatabase so I just moved it after I declared it and before main, and it worked.

Comment: @bankey you originally posted that your prototype was `void AccountAccess(BankDatabase bank);` and then you edited your post to say that it was `void AccountAccess(class bank);`.   Obviously the first version was not actually your real code. My vendetta is that you are wasting people's time by making stuff up instead of posting the actual code with the problem.

Comment: @M.M because I am actively trying to get it to work via the inputs all of you are giving me.

Comment: @bankey, you are correct that we don't want your **whole code**. Just a **simplified, compilable, complete** version that demonstrates the problem you're running into.

Comment: @bankey no, because the error "cannot convert argument 1 from 'BankDatabase' to 'bank'" comes because of the line `void AccountAccess(class bank);` . You must have had that line in right from the start and didn't tell anyone.

Comment: @M.M I did have that line right from the start and guess I changed it. So I changed it back. The error was from a different line.

Comment: @bankey although the error message mentioned a different line, the cause of the error is because of that line (as my answer explains). If you change that line back , you will find the same error reappear.